# Modify item in multiple parse function and return updated item?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have an item which will be filled in each of the parse function. I want to return updated item after completion of parsing. Here is my scenario:

My Item class:

```
class MyItem(Item):

    name = Field()
    links1 = Field()
    links2 = Field()
```

I have multiple urls to crawl after login:

in parse function, I'm doing:

```
for url in urls:
    yield Request(url=url, callback=self.get_info)
```

In get_info, I will be extracting 'name' and 'links' in each response:

```
item = MyItem()
item['name'] = hxs.select("//title/text()").extract()
links = []
link = {}
for data in json_parsed_from_response:
    link['name'] = data.get('name')
    link['url'] = data.get('url')
    links.append(link)
item['links1] = links

#similarly, item['links2'] is created.
```

Now, I want to go through each of the url in each of the item['links1] and item['links2'] as(these loops are inside get_info):

```
for link in item['links1']:
    request = Request(url= link['url'], callback=self.get_status)
    request.meta['link'] = link
    yield request

for link in item['links2']:
    request = Request(url= link['url'], callback=self.get_status)
    request.meta['link'] = link
    yield request

 # Where do I return item, can't return item inside generator

def get_status(self, response):

    link = response.meta['link']
    if "good" in response.body:
        link['status'] = 'good'
    else:
        link['status'] = 'bad'

    # Changes made here, will be reflected in item? 
    # Also, I can't return item from here. Multiple items will be returned.
```

I can't figure out from where `item` has to be returned and it should have all the updated data.

Comment: Where do you create the "item" itself? Where do you create "MyItem"? Can you show the whole code?

Comment: It's there in get_info. Sorry, can't post code, its big. I have posted exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but unless you give out some more details I can't understand the design of your code and therefore I can't help... The best suggestion I have is to create a list of **MyItem**s and append each item you create to that list. The values should change as you change them. So you should be able to iterate over the list and see the updated items.

Comment: There is no list of MyItem, only one instance of MyItem. Also, as you told, I think item's field should be updated from any of the parse function since we are passing reference. Lets consider it updates properly, but from which function item should be returned? I have written comments in each function, please check. At the  end I should get only item with all data. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Where do you create this one MyItem instance? Check this instance at the end. You might not need to return.

Comment: It is created get_info, updated question. And, I have to return it, otherwise json will not be created.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using get_info as a callback rather than calling it directly (and then being able to catch a return from it)?

Comment: I have to parse response each of the `url` in `urls`. It happens in parse function(called by default) as mentioned in question.